# by having listing id, only id is hiding not with complete li

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML, and want to target hiding the Listing `<li>` with the input

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/szUgd/)

while hiding the inputs, even `li` should be hided.

kindly help....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#city').show();
$('#target_school_id').hide();
$('#zip_code').hide();

$("#select_type").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
        //alert('id='+id);
    if (id=="by_location"){
        $('#city').show();
        $('#school_name').show();
        $('#state').show();         
        $('#zip_code').hide();          
    }
    else if(id=="by_zip_code")
    {
        $('#city').hide();
        $('#school_name').hide();
        $('#state').hide();
        $('#target_school_id').hide();
        $('#zip_code').show();
    }
    else if(id=="by_school_id")
    {
        $('#city').hide();
        $('#school_name').show();
        $('#state').hide();
        $('#target_school_id').hide();
        $('#zip_code').hide();
    }
});

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bladebreaker/szUgd/1/) is the solution to your problem

```
you just have to hide their parents too.. using .parent()
```

Comment: Current : $('#city').show();
As said : $('li #city').show();

is this the one your are saying ??